# Help showing that every walk of length $k$ from $x$ to $y$ in a graph is a path.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing

If I were to suppose $x$ and $y$ are two vertices in the same connected component of a graph, and let $k$ be the distance between them, how would I prove that every walk of length $k$ from $x$ to $y$ in the graph is a path?

I am looking over my course notes but I am getting really confused between the different types of graphs and walks.

So, suppose $G$ is a graph which contains a unique path between any two vertices. G is clearly connected. $G$ cannot contain a cycle, because a cycle contains two distinct paths between any pair of vertices in it.

Comment: Depends in course definitions, to an extent. But you probably will have: a path is a walk with no cycles; distance is the shortest path between two vertices. So if the walk has length k, and had a cycle, you can cut that cycle out and get a path from the walk which - given cycle length > 0 - makes the length of the path < k. Contradiction to distance k.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if you have not proved this already, try to show that every $u$-$v$ walk in a graph contains a $u$-$v$ path. Given this, consider your walk from $x$ to $y$ of length $k$. This walk contains a path. If the path is not equal to the entire walk, what can you say about the length of the path? How might this contradict $d(x,y)=k$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If a walk is not a path, there is a repeated vertex: Something like this: $x,a,b,...,i,...,i,...y$.  But then the segment $i...i$ can be removed and replaced by a single $i$ giving a shorter walk from $x$ to $y$.